# Where should I ask questions about real world materials for a game crafting system?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Some background on the question, I'm making a fantasy themed RPG from the ground up with a focus on an in-depth, but simple to understand, crafting system.

I'm doing my research and finding the numbers on materials, but I don't know which ones are most important to their specific tasks. I'm trying to boil down the materials down to 2 or 3 significant properties (not counting weight since that's a given) that affect durability, damage, etc.

So, in the context of making an RPG with a mostly-realistic representation of materials, I wanted to know which Stack Exchange the questions along the following lines should be asked in:

- What are the most important properties of a wood when making a shield?
- What properties of a wood determine how ideal it is for a polearm haft?
- What properties determine how well a metal would work for armor?

Given that it's for an RPG, part of me thinks Game Dev, but I'm also using real-world material properties so it's not quite there, either.

Comment: [Worldbuilding.se] confuses me enough that I won't answer that you should use it but you should at least look at their help center to see if it sounds like something that might be on topic for them.

Comment: Worldbuilding did occur to me, but I think they would try to shut these questions down as "off-topic" if I asked them.

Comment: They have a sandbox on their meta where you can propose new questions and find out if they'd be on topic... https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions

Comment: Yeah, Worldbuilding isn't the best place for this. You *might* get an answer at Game Dev, though it gets iffy (its not off-topic, but...you won't have any experts). That said, I'd probably hit Game Dev first for an arbitrary question in the vein of "I need to find some info on real world subject Y for a game." Heck, ask me a question about [botanical geography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytogeography) and [hyperaccumulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperaccumulator) and I could answer it; I did a crap ton of research for some game mechanics...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps https://engineering.stackexchange.com/

I didn't participate on that site yet but I think that questions about real world materials for building things on real life where durability, strength among other properties are important should be on-topic on a site named Engineering.

The [materials tag](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials) is on the top ten and has already 423 questions.